# Buttons are covering Scrollview

Tags: android, layout, button, scrollview

check out this code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="all"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="nextButton"
    android:text="@string/next" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/backbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="prevButton"
    android:text="@string/back" />
```

the result i am getting is that, while the scrollview and text is showing, the buttons at the bottom left and bottom left are on top of the text/scrollview. i have tried using linearlayout, but no luck. help, please.

Comment: Give your scrollview an id and try adding this to your buttons: `android:layout_below="@+id/scrollViewId"`

Comment: try Justin V's answer @mister_dani

Answer (score 1):

Try the following by adding `android:layout_above="@+id/nextbtn"` at your ScrollView :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nextbtn" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@id/nextbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="nextButton"
        android:text="next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="prevButton"
        android:text="back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

edit : Unfortunately the Justin V. answer doesn't work because Android fill the screen with your ScrollView and put your buttons below, out of the screen.

Comment: Thanks, Alex R. how do you suppose i deal with the Button: "id/backbtn" too